# Draw View before displaying during animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have two views in a ViewFlipper and have a fast/complex animation between them. The second view contains a list, so at the moment that view become visibile half way through the animation, getView() is called a bunch of times and causes a very noticeable stutter (usually stalling for the entire second half of the animation)

Ideally I would like to pre-render (measure, layout, draw) the second view before starting the animation, but I have not found a simple way to do this.

I have also explored using the drawing cache, off-screen canvases, etc - but I cannot find a simple way to achieve this either. Seems to be a problem anyone animating between two views would have. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by specifying a layer type and calling buildLayer() before you start your animation, which forces rendering the view.

```
newView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
newView.buildLayer();
```

You could also use LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE. The default value is LAYER_TYPE_NONE, which prevents buildLayer() to do anything.